# records missing during ibm queue replication

Tags: db2, db2-luw

We have set up IBM Queue replication. our source database is db2 11.1.1.4, source table has a unique field (id), date and payload field, payload is lob. Until today replication works correctly, but today we encountered a problem, our application, for some requests, sets the date field incorrectly for 3 days ago, and replication only replicates those records that are for 3 days ago, in source database we have records that are for today, but those records are not replicated in the target database and according to APPLYMON and CAPMON tables we have less than 1 seconds latency for capture and apply, what might be the problem? there are no errors in capture and apply logs and database logs.